# Why did the blind man at Bethsaida look up and see men as if they were taller trees?

Tags: jesus

> And he looked **up**, and said, I see men as **trees**, walking. Mark 8:24 KJV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story of the healing of the Blind man in Mark 8:22-26 contains a series of statements that all show a progression.  I will split these apart to as to make them parallel:

**A: Bethsaida/village/home**

- V22: they came to Bethsaida
- V23: He led him out of the village (to be healed)
- V26: He sent him home (and said) do not go to the village

Note that Jesus felt it necessary to enter the village and then take the man out of it and then prevents from returning

**B: Hands/touch**

- V22: People ask Jesus to heal the blind man by **touching** him
- V23a: Jesus takes **hold** of the **hand** of the blind man
- V23b: Jesus **lays** his **hands** on the man to heal him
- V25: Jesus lays His hands on the man's eyes

**C: Βλέπω = "I see"**

- V23: βλέπεις = "you see"
- V24a: ἀναβλέψας = "having looked up" (after bowing his head from Christ's touching)
- V24: βλέπω = "I see" (also ὁρῶ = "I see")
- V25a: διέβλεψεν = "he opened his eyes"
- V25b: ἐνέβλεπεν = "he began to see"

The impression is that Jesus decided to heal the man in stages rather than all at once/immediately.  Note Ellicott's comments in V24 -

> From the point of view which looks on our Lord’s miracles as having a
> symbolic character, and being, as it were, acted parables, we may see
> in it that which represents an analogous stage in the spiritual growth
> of men, when truths for which before they had no faculty of vision are
> seen for the first time, but are not as yet apprehended in their full
> or definite proportions. They need a second touch of the Divine Hand,
> the passing away of another film of ignorance or prejudice, and then
> they too see all things clearly.

I am sure Jesus did this as a source of encouragement to various people whom the Lord elects to heal slowly, rather than immediately, so as to sustain the exercise of faith in God for relief from various grievances.

Indeed, according to 2 Cor 12, Paul was refused by God.  Thus, Paul's faith was sustained (in his case) to prevent boasting.